# How to mock function with query with jest

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have this function that include some queries.

```
const dataCollection: Entry<Folder> = (await conn.getEntries({
    type: 'title',
    include: 4,
    limit: 1000,
  })) as Entry<Folder>;
```

I'm mocking like:

jest.spyOn(testConn, 'getEntries').mockReturnValue(dataResponse);

But the result is not returning mocking with the query 'include'.

Comment: You need to mock `dataCollection` this whole function not API call

Comment: and how to mock dataCollection?

Comment: Please provide the minimal, complete code under test, and which one you want to mock

Comment: Please find out the URL I believe you will get better response https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn